# Archive File is corrupt after Groovy FTP upload

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to try an FTP upload from Jenkins to my FTP server with a groovy script.
After the upload, the archive file is corrupt and can not be opened.

I downloaded my archive from the workspace of Jenkins. There is all correct.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPF
import java.io.InputStream

@Grab(group='commons-net', module='commons-net', version='3.6')
def upload(){

 String ftpServer = "ftp.my-domain.com";
 String folder = "/";
 def ftpClient = new FTPClient()




  ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  try {
    InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("deployment.tar.gz")
             ftpClient.connect(ftpServer)
             ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
             ftpClient.login("jenkins@my-domain.com","JenkisPassword")
             ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
            // Store file to server
            ftpClient.storeFile("deployment.tar.gz", is);
            ftpClient.logout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}

upload();
```

Is there any solution for groovy ? or is it a bad way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to call [setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType(int)) before sending the file